# underscore: map through object (even if undefined)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, underscore.js

I'm new to functional javascript, I'd like to make a map that loop through object property and can tell me if the property is not undefined

I have tried, after looking for other answers, this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var elements = {
    user_id: 1,
    role: 'admin',
    username: undefined,
    status: 1,
    credits: undefined,
    timestamp: 12345
};
console.log(elements);
_.object(_.map( elements, function(v,k) {
    console.log(k, v);
}));
```

But I'm stuck on this error:

```
result[list[i][0]] = list[i][1];
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Function._.object (/private/tmp/node_tmp/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:539:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/node_tmp/test.js:11:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

### EDIT:

What I want to achieve is a function that, given certain object, check if the properties are defined and are of the correct type. What I have now is:

```
function isNumeric(value) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(value);
}

function parseElement(elements, QuerySchema) {
    errors = [];
    // TODO: more functional with underscore
    for(var key in elements) {
        if(!elements.hasOwnProperty(key) || !(elements[key])) {
            errors.push({code:'1', description:'Missing parameter', params:[key]});
        } else {
            var val = elements[key];

            if( QuerySchema[key]==Number && !isNumeric(elements[key])) {
                errors.push({code:'2', description:'cast error', params:[key, elements[key]]});
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    var elements = {
        user_id: req.query.user_id,
        asset_id: req.query.asset_id,
        time_start: req.query.time_start,
        duration: req.query.duration,
        status: req.query.status,
        timestamp: req.query.timestamp
    }

    var Schema = {
        user_id: Number,
        asset_id: Number,
        time_start: Number,
        duration: Number,
        status: Number,
        timestamp: Number
    };

    var errors = parseElement(elements, Schema);
    ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this block of code? Could you give us what your desired output should be?

Comment: @redolent ok see the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_Objects converts arrays into objects. Pass either a single list of [key, value] pairs, or a list of keys, and a list of values. If duplicate keys exist, the last value wins.

```
_.object(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]);
```

=> {moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}

```
_.object([['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]]);
```

=> {moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}

since in your _map function you didn't build right array it was given you that error.
Try:

```
_.object(_.map( elements, function(v,k) {
  return [k,v];
}));
```

Your parse element function doesn't really have to be that fancy.

```
function parseElement(elements, Schema) {
 return _.map(elements, function(obj, key) {
 return (obj != null && Schema[key] === obj.constructor) ? true : false;
})};
```

This function gives you an array of true and false. You can see by array index which value works for you and which doesn't;

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to read the underscore.js source code.

If you're just *checking* an object, then you should use `_.each()` http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-13

If you're trying to filter out the undefined elements, then you should use something like maybe `_.reject()` (I just looked at the doc: http://underscorejs.org/#reject)

---

After taking a look at what you're doing specifically, you should iterate through the *keys* of the `Schema` object and check them against the `elements` object.

Without doing the work for you, I would encourage you to look at `_.keys()` – http://underscorejs.org/#keys

---

If you're not familiar enough with closures, here's how you can write a check:

```
var pass_check = true,
    last_error = '';

_.each( obj, function( value, key ){
    if ( /* key check */ ) {
        pass_check = false;
        last_error = "Failed check: " + key;
    }
    if ( /* value check */ ) {
        pass_check = false;
        last_error = "Failed check: " + value;
    }
});
```